# Tesseract OCR not working as expected, unable to get the complete text from image. c#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, text-extraction

I have image with all numbers in it(PFA image)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9xiq.png), all the numbers are not coming in the output text. Text i recieved after running below code is :

> 75491024385252003967

. i have downloaded my traning data from : **https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata**

Can anyone guide me what is it dat i am doing wrong here?

```
enter code here


       string file = @"C:\Images\image.jpg";
        char[] textArray = null;
        using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
        {

            using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(file))
            {

                using (var page = engine.Process(img))
                {
                    var text = page.GetText();
                    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\t|\n|\r|\s", "");
                    text = text.Trim(' ');
                    textArray = text.ToCharArray();

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't found a solution, you might want to try our Leadtools OCR which is licensed out by LEAD Technologies where I work. I was able to use that image in our .NET OCR demo and get all of the numbers in a single string. I didn't need to use training data at all. The extracted text includes the whitespace between characters, but you can use that same Regex command to fix that. Here is a screenshot of the resulting pdf:

Results exported to PDF

[image: Results exported to PDF]